# Run excel macro with Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, excel

So I have a script that open an existing workbook, execute a macro, save and quit the workbook. It work on windows using win32com.client and I would like to do the same on linux but I cant find how to run a macro without win32com.client.

my script on windows :

```
import os
import win32com.client

if os.path.exists("Book1.xlsm"):
    path = os.getcwd()
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path+"\\Book1.xlsm")
    xl.Application.Run("Book1.xlsm!sheet1.color")
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False
    xl.Application.Save()
    xl.DisplayAlerts = True
    xl.Workbooks.Close()
    xl.Application.Quit()
    del xl
```

Comment: why are you explicitly deleting `x1`?

Comment: I found this on another topic. but it will probably work without it

Comment: @YannQ - I removed the (inappropriate) "macros" tag from the question.  I would normally have replaced it with a "vba" tag instead, but I don't think the question really has anything to do with the VBA code - it seems to only be about creating the Excel Application object.  (Once that's created, running the VBA code, and using the `Workbooks.Open` method, etc, will all work normally.)

Comment: So I'm trying to use `openpyxl` and with this I'm able to open and modify a workbook but I can find a way to run my macro (witch is already written in the workbook). It doesn't seems to have an equivalent to `wb.Application.Run("macro")`

Comment: please update if you found any solution as i am also in same situation

Comment: Any solution found for this?